# Get class attributes without making an instance

Tags: php, forms, oop

Here's the thing: I'm trying to make an automatic form generator based on my Model classes.

I would like to know if I can do it in PHP without first instatiating the model class. Personally I'm thinking it may be hard for PHP is not strong-typed, but I want to check.

Can I get the attributes, its names and types(probably the hardest part) from a non-static class in PHP without instantiating it? (Maybe reflection?)

Would it be a better idea to get the names and types from the Database and then create the form?

Comment: Getting types for a class property is hard, because PHP is loose-typed and you can change a property from one type to another at any time

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to **modelize** your entities using "Schema Definition Language", **XSD** files
After that, generate both of your PHP classes and forms using your XSD models ( in Java there is JAXB, but a small reseach in internet will give you a JAXB's like :) )

This Technique will ensure that if you decide to update your models, PHP Classes and Forms will be automatically generated (like Maven in Java)